# Matching zip with geocode fetch too many data in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geocode

Hi I have included this in my gemfile:

```
gem 'geokit'
gem 'geokit-rails'
```

and written this code in my model

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :zip_and_city_match
  def zip_and_city_match
    p "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
    geo = Geokit::Geocoders::MultiGeocoder.geocode(self.zip)
    p 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
    p geo   
    p 'city'
    p geo.city     
    p "sssssssssssssssssssssss"        
  end
end
```

So when I give `contact_attributes"=>{"current_address1"=>"test1dinsh", "current_address2"=>"awwwwwwwww", "country"=>"IN", "city"=>"Indore", "zip"=>"452001"}`
 then it gives me this type of output:

```
"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
#<Geokit::GeoLoc:0xbec3078 @all=[#<Geokit::GeoLoc:0xbec3078 ...>, #<Geokit::GeoLoc:0xbec83e8 @all=[#<Geokit::GeoLoc:0xbec83e8 ...>], @street_address=nil, @sub_premise=nil, @street_number=nil, @street_name=nil, @city=nil, @state=nil, @state_code="Republic of Bashkortostan", @state_name="Republic of Bashkortostan", @zip="452001", @country_code="RU", @province="Republic of Bashkortostan", @success=true, @precision="city", @full_address="Republic of Bashkortostan, Russia, 452001", @lat=54.1245735, @lng=54.1369126, @provider="google", @district="Belebeyevsky District", @country="Russia", @accuracy=4, @suggested_bounds=#<Geokit::Bounds:0xbec30f0 @sw=#<Geokit::LatLng:0xbec312c @lat=54.098381, @lng=54.110801>, @ne=#<Geokit::LatLng:0xbec31f4 @lat=54.1550891, @lng=54.158854>>>, #<Geokit::GeoLoc:0xbec92fc @all=[#<Geokit::GeoLoc:0xbec92fc ...>], @street_address=nil, @sub_premise=nil, @street_number=nil, @street_name=nil, @city="Indore", @state=nil, @state_code="MP", @state_name="Madhya Pradesh", @zip="452001", @country_code="IN", @province="MP", @success=true, @precision="city", @full_address="Indore, Madhya Pradesh 452001, India", @lat=22.7081955, @lng=75.8824422, @provider="google", @district="Indore", @country="India", @accuracy=4, @suggested_bounds=#<Geokit::Bounds:0xbec8438 @sw=#<Geokit::LatLng:0xbec844c @lat=22.6845079, @lng=75.8606602>, @ne=#<Geokit::LatLng:0xbec84ec @lat=22.7359325, @lng=75.91539259999999>>>], @street_address="Mičurinova", @sub_premise=nil, @street_number=nil, @street_name="Mičurinova", @city="Subotica", @state=nil, @state_code="Vojvodina", @state_name="Vojvodina", @zip="452001", @country_code="RS", @province="Vojvodina", @success=true, @precision="street", @full_address="Mičurinova, Subotica 452001, Serbia", @lat=46.0988609, @lng=19.6422459, @provider="google", @district="Severnobački okrug", @country="Serbia", @accuracy=7, @suggested_bounds=#<Geokit::Bounds:0xbec1bc4 @sw=#<Geokit::LatLng:0xbec1bec @lat=46.0973894197085, @lng=19.6407217697085>, @ne=#<Geokit::LatLng:0xbec1c3c @lat=46.1000873802915, @lng=19.6434197302915>>, @neighborhood="Novo Selo">
'city'
"Subotica"
"sssssssssssssssssssssss"
```

Please guide me why its giving this city how I will fetch correct city i.e I had given Indore then it has to match with it only. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [multiple results](https://github.com/geokit/geokit#multiple-results) section of geokit gem readme. As it states, you can obtain more than one result for unclear queries. This is just what happens when you ask for results by single `zipcode`:

```
geo = Geokit::Geocoders::MultiGeocoder.geocode('452001')
geo.all.map{|i| i.full_address}
# => ["Mičurinova, Subotica 452001, Serbia", "Republic of Bashkortostan, Russia, 452001", "Indore, Madhya Pradesh 452001, India"]
```

As you see, there were three different locations with the same `zipcode` found. You could select the one you need manually:

```
geo.all.find{|i| i.country == 'India'}
```

Or you could provide more information to geocoding service (if possible):

```
def zip_and_city_match
  zip_and_country = self.zip + " " + self.country
  geo = Geokit::Geocoders::MultiGeocoder.geocode(zip_and_country)
  # => should return only one result
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, its giving me correct city and state.

```
require 'geokit'
geo = GeoKit::Geocoders::MultiGeocoder.geocode('Indore, 452001')
#or 
geo = GeoKit::Geocoders::MultiGeocoder.geocode('India, 452001')
if geo.success
  geo.state # => MP
  geo.city  # => Indore
end
```

You should not try with zip code only, you can try with country and zip code though, as same zip code you can find in other countries also. It may return multiple or wrong.